# How do I query _Open or _Click?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I tried to query _Open and _Click in Automation (Marketing Cloud), but I got errors all the time. Does anybody know what I did wrong?[image: Query][image: Data-Extension]

Comment: Can you provide the SQL outside of an image and show what error you are receiving?

Comment: Need more info regarding error as Gortonington said.  The `ENT.` activity is used when the data extension is outside the business unit (ie. shared or parent). You might start there.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think `_Open` data is recorded at the parent business unit level, only the business unit in which the send takes place. Try dropping the `ENT` prefix

Comment: I already tried that, but still receive the errors -_-

Comment: Can you provide the error message you receive?

Answer (score 0):

You have SubscriberKey set as a Primary Key, and with Opens and Clicks you will most likely have multiple records for a SubscriberKey.

Either adjust your SQL to select the first record per subscriber, or remove the Primary Key in your data extension